# Reuseable xhtml wrapper that works well on all devices

Tags: css, xhtml, resize, wrapper

I am a freelance web designer. While I have a good understanding of XHTML and divs some of the sites I’m creating are not displaying well on mobiles in the vertical position. The last site I completed required me to make the website span the whole. I achieved this using 100% width but my navigation bar at the top of the page moved when the browser was reduced.

In a nutshell I am posting this job to be supplied with  XHTML code that will provide me with a  reusable container that will resize well on pc, mobile or pad:

Please see the example websites below. These are the dimensions, look and feel I’m trying to achieve.

Here is some of the css I used on my last project.

```
#backgrdwrapper
{
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper
{
width: 100%px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
width: 100%px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #000000;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#spaceheader

{

height:15px;

}


#navigation
{
width: 1000px;
height: 65px;
background-color: #000000;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:1px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content
{
width: 980px;

padding: 10px 10px;
background-color: #000000;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Please see the example websites below. These are the dimensions, look and feel I’m trying to achieve.

www.wemakewebsites.com

www.seamonster.com

www.double-eye.com

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

I myself am I freelance web developer as well and spent months on end trying to figure out how to correctly position all my websites so that they would work on both my laptop, iPhone, and iPad. After quite some time of doing this I figured out how this is done.

I believe I may see your problem, for your navigation width you are using 1000px and your content width is 980px. It should never be more than 960px. Since that's basically the magic number for making everything fit. So all you would have to do is change your navigation width and content width to 960px and you should be all good.

I do see though that you tried to compensate for the content area. While that did work it is not exactly "right". So you can leave your content area as is if you like but if you do change your width to 960 for it make sure that you get rid of your paddings.

So here would be what you want to change your #navigation and #content to:

```
#navigations {
 position: relative;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto 0;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}

#content {
 position: relative;
 width: 960px;
 margin 0px auto 0;
}
```

That should work for you.

Cheers!